# Unable to create system image with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to display system image with Swift UI.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "star.fill")
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct SwiftUIView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}
#endif
```

But I do not see any image in the preview area. Why?

[image]

Comment: This works for me. Are you sure that the preview is actually working (for anything)? You could try adding a .foregroundColor(.red) to it just to see if it makes a difference

Comment: Yes, preview is working. I've added foregroundColor but it is still doesn't work.

Comment: I noticed that if I set .font(.title) then image appears! It is strange.

Comment: Works fine without that for me. Can you edit your question to include the *entire* code?

Comment: I have your exact code, and it works fine. I can also adjust it by using .foregroundColor, .font etc with preview in real time. I would try restarting xcode and see. It *is* a beta, so who knows...

Comment: Actually, I can't get your code to work at all using SwiftUIView. Not sure why you have that. If I use ContentView (which is there by default), it works.

Comment: I've changed simulator from iPhone Xs to iPhone Xr and image appears.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with certain Image(systemNamed:) SF Symbol.

Changing the preview device to "iPhone XR" solves the issue.  I think it’s a bug.

You can change the preview device as below:

```
#if DEBUG
struct SwiftUIView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
          .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "iPhone XR"))
    }
}
#endif
```